# Drone's motion is unstable with ROS topics

Tags: python, ros, ar.drone, rospy

Drone's motion is not stable with rostopics...what can I do ?

```
import rospy 
import time

#import library untuk mengirim command dan menerima data navigasi dari quadcopter
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import String 
from std_msgs.msg import Empty 
from ardrone_autonomy.msg import Navdata

#import class status untuk menentukan status ddari quadcopter
from drone_status import DroneStatus

COMMAND_PERIOD = 1000


class AutonomousFlight():
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = ""
        rospy.init_node('forward', anonymous=False)
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)
        self.pubTakeoff = rospy.Publisher("ardrone/takeoff",Empty, queue_size=10)
        self.pubLand = rospy.Publisher("ardrone/land",Empty, queue_size=10)
        self.pubCommand = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel',Twist, queue_size=10)
        self.command = Twist()
        #self.commandTimer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(COMMAND_PERIOD/1000.0),self.SendCommand)
        self.state_change_time = rospy.Time.now()    
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.SendLand)

    def SendTakeOff(self):
        self.pubTakeoff.publish(Empty()) 
        self.rate.sleep()

    def SendLand(self):
        self.pubLand.publish(Empty())


    def SetCommand(self, linear_x, linear_y, linear_z, angular_x, angular_y, angular_z):
        self.command.linear.x = linear_x
        self.command.linear.y = linear_y
        self.command.linear.z = linear_z
        self.command.angular.x = angular_x
        self.command.angular.y = angular_y
        self.command.angular.z = angular_z
        self.pubCommand.publish(self.command)
        self.rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    try: 
        i = 0
        uav = AutonomousFlight()

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            uav.SendTakeOff()
            if i <= 30 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,1,0,0,0)
                i+=1
            elif i<=60 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,0,0,0,0)
                i+=1
            else:
                uav.SendLand()

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I need to just takeoff, go up and go to hover mode,

```
 uav.SendTakeOff()
            if i <= 30 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,1,0,0,0)
                i+=1
            elif i<=60 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

after take off, this code makes the drone go to little back and some random motion and going up and going to hover mode. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is your second code snipped really correct? There is a parameter missing in the last call of `SetCommand`.

Comment: Besides that: to stabilize the motion of the drone, you will need some controller (e.g. a PID controller) that reacts on undesired movements of the robot, to compensate them. Note that for this, you need to have some feedback from the drone about the motion it is doing. Do you have any sensors for that?

Comment: @luator : yeah it's just a typo and there is no sensor for it

Comment: Then, I am afraid there is not much you can do. When the drone is completely blind, it cannot recognize errors and thus also not compensate them. So if possible add a sensors to the robot (or use an external tracking system). Note, however, that I never worked with flying robots, so I don't know what the best solution would be here. I suggest to do some research on what other people are using.

Comment: Hi @luator can you post that PID controller as your answer ? I ll accept it now. Drone works perfectly with PID controller.